# Is it possible to disable pylint missing docstring error for short functions and methods?

Tags: python, coding-style, pylint

Pylint reports an error for every function and method (except `__init__`) that has no docstring.

This is generally desirable, so I don't want to disable it globally (in `pylintrc`, or at file level).

However, in my opinion, there are cases where a docstring is not necessary, and even harmful. For example:

```py
def get_foo(self, foo_id):
    """Gets foo by its id."""
    return foos[foo_id]
```

This method is a simple getter that is completely described by its signature. Having to write a docstring is harmful in that it creates duplicate maintenance if the method is changed.

I'd like to be able to set (e.g. in `pylintrc`) something like `docstring_threshold=3`, to suppress missing docstring errors if the function or method is shorter than 3 lines of code. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using pylint 1.3.1 add a line to you pylintrc `docstring-min-length=10` for example.

It is described in the generated pylintrc `pylint --generate-rcfile` file as

> Minimum line length for functions/classes that require docstrings, shorter ones are exempt.

[Documentation reference](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#basic-checker-options).